# Стоит ли добавлять /idea/modules.xml в gitignore?

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea

Стоит ли добавлять `/idea/modules.xml` в `gitignore`? О чем там пишется?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/callre.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/callreport.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

Вот это написано, а почему надо добавить всю папку, как потом studio его поймет, или я чего-то не понимаю

**Обновление**

Я делаю дома и на работе пуш, в этом файле каждый раз меняется местами эти строчки:

```
 <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" />
 <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/callre.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/callreport.iml" />
```

то одна, то другая сверху

Comment: Ну откройте и посмотрите, что там. Вообще всю папку idea надо добавить в игнор, она к самому проекту никак не относится.

Comment: можно добавлять файлы, если в них нет абсолютных путей, я думаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас нет жестких требований к среде разработки, тогда в контроль версий помещайте только те файлы, которые непосредственно относятся к приложению. А все IDE-зависимые директории -- в игнор.